# How to fit an image to a div with table-cell display

Tags: html, css

I have the following HTML and CSS. As you can see I have my main div divided into two parts of 70 and 30%. Also, the inner divs have a display property set to table cell. On the right inner div, I have image slides which don't fit the div 100% both vertically and horizontally. I would also want to display the top-layer text on hovering on the images. How do I fit the images to the available space? How do I display the text exactly at the center of the images on image hover?

HTML:

```
<div id="investment">

    <div id="left ">

    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <img class="slides" src="..../img01.jpeg">
        <img class="slides" src="..../img02.jpeg">
        <img class="slides" src="..../img03.jpeg">
        <p id="top-layer">text here</p>
    </div>

 </div>
```

CSS :

```
#left {
    width: 70%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }
 #right {  
   position: relative;
   width: 30%;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
 #right #top-layer{    
   position: absolute;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

Comment: can you fiddle here?

Comment: display image horizontally or vertically

Comment: @Bhargav it is a slideshow so the images are stacked on each other

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for following solution.

May be it will halp you!

You are using `table-cell` but `table-cell` property doen't work untill it's parent don't have `table` property.

**Horizontally align -**

```css
#investment {
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

#left {
  width: 70%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.slide {
  display: table;
}

#right {
  position: relative;
  width: 30%;
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#right img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

.imageBlock {
  position: relative;
  display: table-cell;
}

.imageBlock p {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  margin:0;
}

.imageBlock:hover p {
  opacity: 1;
}

#right #top-layer {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 0;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#right:hover #top-layer {
  position: absolute;
  opacity: 1;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div id="investment">
  <div id="left ">
    THIS IS BLANK SPACE AND WIDTH = 70%
  </div>
  <div id="right">
    <div class="slide">
      <div class="imageBlock">
        <img class="slides" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ff00ee/ff00ee">
        <p>HOVER TEXT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="imageBlock">
        <img class="slides" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ffeerr/ffeerr">
        <p>HOVER TEXT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="imageBlock">
        <img class="slides" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/dddddd/dddddd">
        <p>HOVER TEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Vertically align -**

```css
#investment {
  display:table;
  width:100%;
}
#left {
    width: 70%;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
 }
 #right {  
   position: relative;
   width: 30%;
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
#right img {
  min-width:100%;
}
.imageBlock {
  position:relative;
}
.imageBlock p {
  position:absolute;
  opacity:0;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  margin:0;
}
.imageBlock:hover p {
  opacity:1;
}
#right #top-layer {
   position: absolute;
   opacity:0;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
 #right:hover #top-layer{    
   position: absolute;
   opacity:1;
   top: 50%;
   left: 50%;
   transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
   display: table-cell;
   vertical-align: middle;
 }
```

```html
<div id="investment">
    <div id="left ">
      THIS IS BLANK SPACE AND WIDTH = 70%
    </div>
    <div id="right">
      <div class="imageBlock">
        <img class="slides" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ff00ee/ff00ee">
         <p>HOVER TEXT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="imageBlock">
        <img class="slides" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/ffeerr/ffeerr">
         <p>HOVER TEXT</p>
      </div>
      <div class="imageBlock">
        <img class="slides" src="https://dummyimage.com/300x200/dddddd/dddddd">
         <p>HOVER TEXT</p>
      </div>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: the hover thing works perfectly but the images don't occupy the cell 100%. they are just centered vertically and horizontally.

Comment: Check Updated answer